# django admin - how to override the default <select> view for foreign key?

Tags: django-admin

I have 2 django model

```
class Location
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Client
  location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And I have the following admin.py

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fieldsets = [
    ('Client Details', {'fields': ['name']}),
    ('Location Details', {'fields': ['location']}),
]


admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

When I try to add a Client I like to have a editable "location" fields i.e. address and city text fields. django by default gives a  list.. how can I get the fields from the foregin tables?

any way I can do this? I don't wish to register the Location table in the admin.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could put an inline table for the location and use the method queryset to handle the field values.
So, this is the ideia of the solution:

```
class LocationInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Location

    def queryset(self, request):
        query = ... #your custom query here
        qs = super(LocationInline, self).queryset(request).filter(query)
        return qs


class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [LocationInline]
    fieldsets = [
        ('Client Details', {'fields': ['name']}),
    ]
```

**Edit:**
There is another way to do it in django 1.1.

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Client Details', {'fields': ['name']}),
        ('Location Details', {'fields': ['location']}),
    ]

def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):

    if db_field.name = "location":
        locations = Location.objects.filter( ... ) #your query

        kwargs["queryset"] = Location.objects.filter(query)

    return super(ClientAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

The docs are here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

It's an old question, but answering this can help a lot of other people too.
So, I hope it helps! ;)